# Unable to perform slideup animation on RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to perform slide up of layout. The slide up should show from bottom which contains some text.
Below is the code. There are not error on build but the layout doesn't slide up.
The activity calls extends AppCompatActivity.

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="75%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

layout file:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
ViewGroup hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.time);
hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this is in your slid_up animation file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Comment: This is not working. Can you suggest some other solution. I want the layout to be at bottom with height of 100dp which is on top.

Comment: No luck again. Any mistake in my code above ? Should I change RelativeLayout to something else ?

Comment: LinearLayout   also you can add

Answer (score 0):

try this :

for bottomup.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromYDelta="75%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
 android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Now for your layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="slideUpDown" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

add a `onClick` method

in code:

```
public void slideUpDown(final View view) {
    if (!isPanelShown()) {
        // Show the panel
        Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.bottom_up);

        hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
        hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private boolean isPanelShown() {
    return hiddenPanel.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
```

Where `hiddenPanel = findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);`